# Mysql bash Incorrect database name when database exist?

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm currently working on a migration script with a bash script.
When I tried to open a database via a variable in my bash script the database name is incorrect.
I got the following error
"'RROR 1102 (42000): Incorrect database name 'development"

```
mysql --batch --host=********** --user=**** --password=***** $dbName -e "${fileContents}"
```

When I do the this in my bash script the database exists

```
mysql --batch --host=********** --user=**** --password=***** development -e "${fileContents}"
```

The variable fileContents are the migration scripts in SQL.
The variable dbName is the name of the database.

I get the database names from a table in my database via the following lines

```
databaseNames=()
shopt -s lastpipe
mysql --batch --raw  --host=***** --user=**** --password=***** -e 'SELECT database_name FROM users.organisations'  | while read dbName guid; do
    if [ $i -gt 0 ]
    then
        databaseNames+=($dbName)
    fi
    i=$(($i + 1))
done
```

The names in the database array seem to be right, but I think that the array messes things up.
I loop true the array as follows.

```
for dbName in "${databaseNames[@]}" do
```

Comment: please update the question with the output from `typeset -p databaseNames` (this will show us the exact contents of the array)

Comment: Thanks for your reaction markp-fuso
I added the typeset -p databaseNames and this is the result:
`[0]=$'dev_ido\r' [1]=$'empty_organisation\r`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is empty. You have to change your while loop to

```
while read dbName guid; do
      databaseNames+=($dbName)
done < <(mysql --batch --raw  --host=$host --port=$port --user=$user --password=$password  --database="yourdatabase" -e 'SELECT database_name FROM users.organisations;')
```

Then

```
for dbName in "${databaseNames[@]}"
do
  echo $dbName
  mysql --batch --raw  --host=$host --port=$port --user=$user --password=$password  --database="$dbName" -e '${fileContents};')
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ufopilot,

I tried to change the array and nothing changed on the result.
The database name is still incorrect. With the comment from Markp-fuso I tried to log the array. This is the output
`[0]=$'dev_ido\r' [1]=$'empty_organisation\r`
So I think that the \r also causes some problems

Comment: After some trying, I figgered out, the last character is the problem in the string. After removing the last character the databasename was correct  
`${dbName::-1}`
After that I  got the following result
`ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1: Table 'empty_organisation.db_version' doesn't exist`
This result was expected.